# need to code for one format of a logical

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

One of the files here is 'multi format'. How do I code the one I need? the file is OEIND1, this code is created by the IBM I tool from the query. I see you cannot use format in SQL.
So the only way is to use the Physical File?

```
SELECT
   ALL       T01.OHORDD, T03.IHINV#, T01.OHORDT, T01.OHJOB3, T01.OHORD#,
             T02.IDPRLC, T02.IDNTU$*(IDSHP#) AS EXTSHP, T02.IDPRT#
   FROM      ASTDTA/OEORHDOH T01 LEFT OUTER JOIN
             ASTDTA/OEIND1 T02
   ON        T01.OHORD# = T02.IDORD# LEFT OUTER JOIN
             ASTDTA/OEINHDIH T03
   ON        T01.OHORD# = T03.IHORD#
   WHERE     T01.OHOSTC = 'CL'
     AND     T01.OHORDD >= 20120101
   ORDER BY  T01.OHORD# ASC
```

Comment: Seems the *tool* alluded was the Retrieve QM Query (RTVQMQRY), and "from the query" refers to a Query Definition (QRYDFN) from which retrieval is allowed with *YES or *ONLY specification on the Allow Query Definition (ALWQRYDFN) parameter on that retrieve command. In that case, the Analyze Query (ANZQRY) should have notified of the inability to retrieve an accurate definition from the Query/400 [aka IBM i Query] object into a Query Management Query (QMQRY) source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-format logicals are DDS-only.  SQL does not understand how to process these.  Use the underlying PF.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-format logical files are created by references to several physical files, where each contributes records in it's own format.  You only want one format, so you want to use the physical file that contains that format.

If you actually did want information from multiple formats, then join the relevant physical files, or perhaps UNION or such.  In SQL you should be referring to the physicals anyway.  If you have specified the physical, the optimizer will evaluate the logicals, and automatically use one if it works out to be a good match for whay you have requested, and the most efficient way to get your results.  Trust the SQE optimizer.

Comment: You should be referring to the physicals **if** no logical (including views) provides a more appropriate set of columns and an appropriate set of rows. For multi-format LFs, there is no choice. Of course, maybe in most cases LFs are created with an implicit field list anyway; so there's no advantage with them. But _most_ LF indexes out there are acceptable to the SQE.